# Log4j not printing log from internal jar

Tags: java, servlets, log4j

1. I have a servlet inside HelloWorld.war from which i do log.info it works fine when executed.
2. I have a method named myMethod() in a java class inside MyJar.jar which calls a method and that method does log.info & this also works fine.
3. when i create a servlet which calls myMethod() present in jar file then it doesn't  print log.info which is present in the myMethod().

How can be enable logging for a web application which can print log from jar files present inside war ?

Comment: Can you please add what Application server and version you are using. JBoss 6 , Tomcat 7 etc.
I suspect you may have more than one log4j configuration file. Does the the JAR and the WAR have different log4j configuration files. Can you please verify that there is only one.

Comment: I am.using tomcat 7 and there is only one configuration file. I tried adding one in war and one in jar also but that didn't worked so I removed it.

Comment: Is there a log4j file in your tomcat?